# Informatica & Git: Version Control

Tags: git, version-control, informatica

I'm relatively new to Informatica but from what I've been told it seems like Informatica doesn't play nice with third party version control systems like Git because of Informatica's proprietary XML file structure. Unfortunately the default Informatica VCS is not an option for me due to my requirements. Is there a way that I can version control my file system by supporting classic Git operations on other files of mine (e.g. shell scripts), but only allow complete overrides on Informatica XML files?

Comment: You can tell git that certain files are to be considered binary, even if they look textual. Google for ".gitattributes".

Comment: Why do you think XML won't play nice with Git? XML is plain text, so Git should be able to track it fine, the only issue I can see is you might have difficulty merging if other users will be updating it concurrently. Are you actually putting your *entire* filesystem in a Git repo? What do you mean by "allow complete overrides" for the XML files?

Comment: @ScottWeldon Yes, XML files generally work fine with Git. However, this XML file must not be merged due to its proprietary nature. The file could be merged, however, the resulting XML file would not work properly in Informatica. This is why I'm looking for a solution that would include my XML files in Git, but restrict these files from being merged and encourage complete replacement. The binary option Lasse mentioned seems to be what I'm looking for, but I'm still open to ideas. I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except the way Lasse mentioned to use `.gitattributes`, You can also **specify the merge stratgeies for certain files (xml files)**.

Assume you want to preserve the version not to replaced during merge, you can set as below:

1. In `.gitattribute`, add the content `filename merge=ours`.
2. Define ours merge strategy by `git config --global merge.ours.driver true`.

Now when you do a merge, git will keep the filename as current version.

More details, you can refer last part (Merge Strategies) in [this article](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes).

Comment: Very interesting, this may actually be very helpful.